# Orbits of some action of SL2 on Pontryagin dual of the field of formal Laurent series

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, power-series, local-fields, unitary-representations

Let $K=\mathbb{F}_2((t))$ be the field of formal Laurent series over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$. Now consider $K^3$ as an additive group and its dual group $\hat{K^3}$, which consists of all continuous group homomorphism $\chi$ from $K^3$ into the circle Group $\mathbb{T}$, i.e., $\chi$ is a unitary character of $K^3$.

It is well-known that for a fixed unitary character $\chi$ of $K$, distinct from the unit character. The mapping $\Phi: K^3\rightarrow \hat{K^3}$, $y\mapsto \chi_y$ is a topological group isomorphism, where $\chi_y$ is the character of $K^3$ defined by $\chi_y(x)=\chi(\sum_{i=1}^3 x_iy_i)$.

Define an action of $SL(2,K)$ on $K^3$ by

$g.x=(ax_1+bx_2,cx_1+dx_2,x_3+x_1x_2+(ax_1+bx_2)(cx_1+dx_2))$,

where 
$g=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
\in SL(2,K)$ and $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in K^3$.

Since characteristic of $K$ is 2, we know that 1=-1. Moreover, $1=det(g)=ad-bc=ad+bc$. It follows that

$g.x=(ax_1+bx_2,cx_1+dx_2,x_3+acx_1^2+bdx_2^2)$.

Since $(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2$ for all $x,y\in K$, it is easy to see this action is well-defined. In some sense, you can regard the semidirect product $K^3\rtimes SL(2,K)$ with this action as the Jacobi group in characteristic 2.

Now we consider the dual action $\alpha: SL(2,K)\curvearrowright \hat{K^3}$ by $(g.\chi)(x)=\chi(g^{-1}x)$.

My question is that what is the corresponding action of $SL(2,K)$ on $K^3$ via the isomorphism $\Phi$? More precisely, find the unique element $y'$ (depending on $g$ and $y$) in $K^3$ such that $\chi_{y'}=\alpha(g)\chi_y$.

The isomorphism $\Phi:K^3\rightarrow \hat{K^3}$ is not canonical and we have to fix $\chi$. My favorite choice is that $\chi:\mathbb{F_2}((t))\rightarrow \mathbb{T}$, $\chi(\sum a_nt^n)=\exp(\frac{2\pi i a_{-1}}{2})$.

My motivation is to compute all the orbits of the dual action $\alpha: SL(2,K)\curvearrowright \hat{K^3}$.

Comment: If $V$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space, then $\hat{V}$ is isomorphic (not canonically) to $V$ as a topological group. View $V$ as an $R$-module, where $R$ is the ring of $K$-linear endomorphism. Then $V$ is naturally a left $R$-module, which makes $\hat{V}$ naturally a (continuous) right-module, which is the commutant in the full endomorphism group (as topological group) of the multiplication by $t$. With a choice of basis, the action is just given by transpose matrices. (...)

Comment: (...) by restriction we have a right group action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ (group of $K$-linear isomorphism, which composed with the inversion map yields a  left action. So if $H$ acts on $K^d$ through a map $j:H\to\mathrm{GL}_d(K)$, then the Pontryagin dual of $K^d$ is $H$-equivariantly isomorphic to $K^d$ with the action of $H$ given by $h\mapsto (j(h)^t)^{-1}$, if I'm correct. In particular when $H\subset\mathrm{GL}_d(K)$ is stable under transposition, then its Pontryagin dual orbit can be identified to its ordinary orbits.

Comment: Dear YCor: Thanks very much for your answer. Is the identification of its Pontryagin dual orbit with its ordinary orbits topological? because I would like to know whether all orbits are locally closed.

Comment: Yes it's topological, but I already wrote it.

Comment: Thanks. So we are done, because the algebraic group SL(2,K) acts algebraically on the affine varety K^3. So all orbits are locally closed in Zariski topology, hence in particualr, in locally compact topology.

Comment: No it's not true in general that orbits are locally closed in the Zariski topology. It's true for intersections of the orbits of the group over an algebraic closure with $K^3$, but in general the orbits can be smaller. I'd expect anyway that orbits are easy to describe and that most of them are closed and remaining ones are singletons or complements of singletons in closed subsets, but since the characteristic is 2 I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe the following fact is not true on K-rational points? If a unipotent group acts on an affine variety, all its orbits are closed. 
BTW, the action of SL(2,K) on K^3 is not given by K-linear endomorphism, because in general $\lambda^2 \neq \lambda$ for $\lambda \in K$.

Comment: I see, so the action on the dual should be computed by hand.